# Is the order of the list returned by getifaddrs(3) important?

Tags: networking, unix

From the [getifaddrs(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) man page:

> The getifaddrs() function creates a linked list of structures describing the network interfaces of the local system [...]

Does the order of this linked list imply a priority, and if so, what does this priority mean?

Comment: What did you see when you compiled and ran the sample program in the man page?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't, but from reading the source it will iterate over my local network interfaces and print them out one by one in the order they are in the linked list. Not sure if that's what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. I suggest comparing the output of the sample program to the output of the `ip address` Linux command.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your suggestion? My question is whether the order of the interfaces in the linked list has any special meaning - e.g. if interfaces in the beginning of the list should be prioritized when selecting a default NIC or something similar to that - not how the output of the sample program looks. I'm not familiar with the `ip address` Linux command though. Could you maybe be a little more explicit in what you'd expect me to see?

Comment: Indeed. And the program's output makes it very obvious.

Comment: As far as I can see, the example source code, output, or man page doesn't explain why the linked list of interfaces are in that particular order or if any significance should be given to the order. It sounds like you misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, absolutely not. Routing is completely separate from that list. I'm not sure there's any document that asserts the negative "this is not priority order" (also it doesn't assert that it's sorted by anything else), but in my work using that list it definitely isn't in any priority order. It's just a list.

More importantly, if the documentation doesn't promise an order, then implementations are free to put it in any order they want (and free to change between releases), so you couldn't rely on it even if it were in some useful order on one platform.